# combining input-prepend and input-append in form-search

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for styling my website.

I've noticed that when doing this:

```
 <form class="form-search  navbar-search pull-right">
                <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
                    <input id="searchQuery" class="search-query" type="search" placeholder="Rechercher" />
                    <a class="btn add-on" href="#">Rechercher</a>
                </div>
```

the input textbox is still rounded on the left side. Which should not be the case when looking at the css:

```
.form-search .input-append .search-query,
.form-search .input-prepend .search-query {
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
```

}

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: here we go:  http://jsfiddle.net/7YGtE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your class '.search-query '

that consist style..

```
.form-search .input-prepend .search-query {
    border-radius: 0 14px 14px 0;
}
```

remove search-query class

Answer (score 1):

You can create the form in the following way :

Jsfiddle  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/mfCAY/)

```
<form class="form-search  navbar-search pull-right">
<div class="input-append input-prepend"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>

<input id="searchQuery" type="search" placeholder="Rechercher" /> <div class="btn-group">
            <button  class="btn">Rechercher</button>

          </div>

  </form>
```

They already have border-radius 0 defined so no need for an extra class to attach with input to set border-radius 0:

```
.input-prepend.input-append input, .input-prepend.input-append select, .input-prepend.input-append .uneditable-input {

border-radius: 0 0 0 0;

   }
```